# Access Type conversion failure importing from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I'm trying to import an Excel to Access DB, and some customer numbers cannot be imported due to Type Conversion Failure. It is 12 entries out of 66 thousand. Normally the customer number is a number, but these 12 are strings like ABCDEFT001. I tried setting the field of the table to Long Text or Short text, they are still not imported (only to ImportError table). Do you know what else I can try? 
Thank you very much in advance!
P.S. I'm trying to import using `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet`

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "Inv level", "Path/to/file.xlsb", True, "Sheetname!"
```

Comment: `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet` tries to be helpful by assuming the datatype for you. What you may want to do is rather than use `acImport`, use `acLink` to link to the Excel Sheet. Then have a query that casts all the fields to the right datatype and selects the data into a Access table.

Answer (score 3):

This strategy links to the excel file, instead of directly importing it, and then selects data out of it and casts any fields that need it to the correct datatype.

```
Sub ImportFromExcel()
    Dim pathToFile As String
    Dim targetTableName As String
    Dim sql As String

    pathToFile = "C:\Path\To\File.xlsx"
    targetTableName = "ImportResults"

    '//create the link
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acLink, _
                              acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, _
                              targetTableName, _
                              pathToFile, _
                              True '//This part only if the excel file has field headers


    '//import
    sql = "SELECT Field1Name, CStr(CustNumber) AS CustNumber, Field3Name INTO NewImportTable FROM " & targetTableName
    CurrentDb.Execute sql

    '//remove the link
    DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, targetTableName
End Sub
```

***Two pitfalls of this code to be aware of:

1) You should delete any table with the name "NewImportTable" before running this code, or you'll get a "Table Already Exists" error.

2) If any errors happen in this `Sub` before you remove the link, you'll have an issue the next time it runs, as it will create a link called "ImportResults1" since "ImportResults" would still exist. The really scary thing is that no errors would be thrown here. It would create "ImportResults1" and then run your sql on "ImportResults"!!

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution, it made my life a bit easier. However, those 6 names like ABCDEFT001 are still missing in the new table. Is there any way to import them, other than manually?

Comment: How strange. Try doing just the linking step, then look at the linked excel table in access and see if you can find those ABCDEFT001 IDs in the linked table. This will help isolate where the problem might be.

Comment: I tried like you suggested, these customer numbers are saved as "Num#!" in the linked table. I also tried converting the whole column to string - strangely enough, it produces the same "Num#!". I guess my only way out is to fill the blank values with the data from excel using Vlookup. Thanks for your time and suggestions, especially the pitfalls! Although excel is a big pitfall in itself for me now :)

Comment: Yes, It appears we are still falling victim to `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet` 's insistence on guessing the datatype for us. I have one final sugguestion - you could try manually importing your excel file, and be sure to set all the column datatype yourself (use Short Text on your customer code column). At the end of the import, you have the option to check a box for "Save Import Steps". This creates a sort of import template that you can trigger with `DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport`. This probably won't work for you if you need any amount of dynamism, but I though I'd suggest it anyways.